# How to convert a record inside a cursor to a column name for a select statement?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to count the number of null values for each column for a given table.

My cursor (t_col_name) holds the list of columns from my table.

```
--select count(*) from sh.costs where promo_id is null  result:78425
DECLARE 
  null_count number;    
  t_col_name ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME%type; 
  CURSOR c_column_name is 
      select COLUMN_NAME from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'COSTS';

BEGIN 
    dbms_output.put_line('Null Count');  
    OPEN c_column_name; 
    LOOP 
    FETCH c_column_name into t_col_name; 
      EXIT WHEN c_column_name%notfound; 
    select count(*) into v_count from sh.costs where t_col_name is 
    null;
    dbms_output.put_line(t_col_name || ' '|| null_count); 
    END LOOP; 
    CLOSE c_column_name;   
END;
```

Actual Result:

```
Null count
PROD_ID 0
TIME_ID 0
PROMO_ID 0
CHANNEL_ID 0
UNIT_COST 0
UNIT_PRICE 0
```

Expected Result:

```
Null count
PROD_ID 0
TIME_ID 0
PROMO_ID 78425
CHANNEL_ID 0
UNIT_COST 0
UNIT_PRICE 0
```

The problem comes from my sql query :

```
select count(*) into v_count from sh.costs where t_col_name is null;
```

t_col_name is passed as a string instead of a column name.

When I change the query to the actual column name I get the right count for the column i.e:

```
select count(*) into v_count from sh.costs where promo_id is null;

Null count
PROD_ID 78425
TIME_ID 78425
PROMO_ID 78425
CHANNEL_ID 78425
UNIT_COST 78425
UNIT_PRICE 78425
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how: it is *dynamic SQL* you need because you have to pass (table and) column name to `SELECT` statement.

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_cnt number;
  3  begin
  4    for cur_r in (select table_name, column_name
  5                  from user_tab_columns
  6                  where table_name in ('EMP', 'DEPT')
  7                 )
  8    loop
  9      execute immediate 'select count(*) from ' || cur_r.table_name ||
 10                        ' where ' || cur_r.column_name || ' is null'
 11              into l_cnt;
 12      dbms_output.put_line(rpad(cur_r.table_name ||'.'|| cur_r.column_name, 20, ' ')
 13         ||': ' || l_cnt);
 14    end loop;
 15  end;
 16  /
DEPT.LOC            : 0
DEPT.DEPTNO         : 0
DEPT.DNAME          : 0
EMP.EMPNO           : 0
EMP.ENAME           : 0
EMP.JOB             : 0
EMP.MGR             : 1
EMP.HIREDATE        : 0
EMP.SAL             : 0
EMP.COMM            : 9
EMP.DEPTNO          : 0

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```